# React Slick Sync - functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

React Slick has got good examples of how to get it going, this one however is in class component, any idea of how to fix the same when making it a functional component

https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/as-nav-for

```
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

export default function SyncSlider() {
  const [nav1, setNav1] = React.useState(null)
  const [nav2, setNav2] = React.useState(null)
    let slider1 = []
    let slider2 = []

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setNav1(slider1)
        setNav2(slider2)
    }, [slider1, slider2])

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Slider Syncing (AsNavFor)</h2>
        <h4>First Slider</h4>
        <Slider
          asNavFor={nav1}
          ref={slider => (slider1 = slider)}
        >
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
        <h4>Second Slider</h4>
        <Slider
          asNavFor={nav2}
          ref={slider => (slider2 = slider)}
          slidesToShow={3}
          swipeToSlide={true}
          focusOnSelect={true}
        >
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );

}
```

Problem looks like is here:

```
    let slider1 = []
    let slider2 = []
```

The sliders show up but do not sync, any thoughts, inputs, solutions on getting this working?

Answer (score 11):

Simple and functional solution (without UseEffect and UseRef) :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';

export default function SyncSlider() {
  const [nav1, setNav1] = useState();
  const [nav2, setNav2] = useState();

    return (
    <div>
      <h2>Slider Syncing (AsNavFor)</h2>
      <h4>First Slider</h4>
      <Slider asNavFor={nav2} ref={(slider1) => setNav1(slider1)}>
        <div>
          <h3>1</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>2</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>3</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>4</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>5</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>6</h3>
        </div>
      </Slider>
      <h4>Second Slider</h4>
      <Slider
        asNavFor={nav1}
        ref={(slider2) => setNav2(slider2)}
        slidesToShow={3}
        swipeToSlide={true}
        focusOnSelect={true}
      >
        <div>
          <h3>1</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>2</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>3</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>4</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>5</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>6</h3>
        </div>
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Demo :** [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nkwgpt?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: @indavinci If you found this answer helpful, please consider marking it as the accepted answer using the checkmark next to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

i had your problem and now its solved for me , this code will work 100% :D

1. delete let slider 1 and let slider 2
2. you need empty dep in useEffect
3. the refs that is used in setstates is undefined for slider so you
   need to write like this:
   setNav1(slider1.current)
   and
   setNav2(slider2.current)
4. refs in sliders should be just like this ref={slider1}

**and here is my code that is still working perfectly for me**

```
 export const ProductGallery = () => {
  const [nav1, setNav1] = useState(null);
  const [nav2, setNav2] = useState(null);
  const slider1 = useRef(null);
  const slider2 = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setNav1(slider1.current);
    setNav2(slider2.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "400px" }}>
      <div>
        <Slider asNavFor={nav2} ref={slider1}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>

        <h4>Pagination slider</h4>

        <Slider
          asNavFor={nav1}
          ref={slider2}
          slidesToShow={3}
          swipeToSlide={true}
          focusOnSelect={true}
        >
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The @burgrandy 's answer may cause error (for example while page scroll)

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

And @ali khakbazan 's answer has a problem, that sync works only in one direction, so that only first carousel influences second, but not vice versa.

Also, both answers a overcomplicated and use unnecessary code.

So I propose to use simplier code, that works without bugs:

```
export default function SyncSlider() {
  const slider1 = useRef(null)
  const slider2 = useRef(null)

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Slider Syncing (AsNavFor)</h2>
      <h4>First Slider</h4>
      <Slider
        asNavFor={slider2.current}
        ref={slider1}
      >
        {list1}
      </Slider>

      <h4>Second Slider</h4>
      <Slider
        asNavFor={slider1.current}
        ref={slider2}
      >
        {list2}
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This seems the best approach. No unnecessary use of setState().

Comment: Anyone coming to this answer, this is the shortest and easiest way without usestate. @indavinci mark this as the correct one

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it. To fix your code, switch the `asNavFor` properties - the first slider should have `asNavFor={nav2}`, and the second slider should have `asNavFor={nav1}`.

```
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

export default function SyncSlider() {
  const [nav1, setNav1] = React.useState(null)
  const [nav2, setNav2] = React.useState(null)
    let slider1 = []
    let slider2 = []

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setNav1(slider1)
        setNav2(slider2)
    }, [slider1, slider2])

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Slider Syncing (AsNavFor)</h2>
        <h4>First Slider</h4>
        <Slider
          asNavFor={nav2}
          ref={slider => (slider1 = slider)}
        >
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
        <h4>Second Slider</h4>
        <Slider
          asNavFor={nav1}
          ref={slider => (slider2 = slider)}
          slidesToShow={3}
          swipeToSlide={true}
          focusOnSelect={true}
        >
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it working as expected for me:

```
const NavigationCarousel = props => {   

    const [topNav, setTopNav] = useState(null); 
    const [bottomNav, setBottomNav] = useState(null);

  let _topSlider = [],
    _bottomSlider = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    setTopNav(_topSlider);
    setBottomNav(_bottomSlider);   
}, [_topSlider, _bottomSlider]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Slider
        asNavFor={bottomNav}

        ref={slider => {
          _topSlider = slider;
        }}
      >
        {topNavElements}
      </Slider>

      <Slider
        asNavFor={topNav}

        ref={slider => {
          _bottomSlider = slider;
        }}
        slidesToShow={slidesToShowBottomNav}
        swipeToSlide={true}
      >
        {bottomNavElements}
      </Slider>
    </div>   ); 
}
export default NavigationCarousel;
```

`topNavElements` and `bottomNavElements` are being passed in from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just use current object from ref while call API that should fix all the problem.

exp:

```
export default function HeroCarousel() {
   const slider = React.useRef<Slider>();
   const next = () => slider.current.slickNext();
   const previous = () => slider.current.slickPrev();

  return (
    <div>
    
      <Slider
        ref={slider}
      >
        {img1}
        {img2}
        {img3}

      </Slider>
     <div className="w-4 text-gray-500 justify-end h-full flex flex-col">
       <svg onClick={previous} className="mt-1 mb-6" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 12 20">
          <path d="M10.59 20L0 10 10.59 0 12 1.33 2.82 10 12 18.67 10.59 20z"></path>
        </svg>
         <svg onClick={next} className="mt-1 mb-3" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 12 20">
           <path d="M0 18.67L9.18 10 0 1.33 1.41 0 12 10 1.41 20 0 18.67z"></path>
         </svg>
      </div> 
    </div>
  );
}
```